# MongoDB: convert array items to documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i've got a nested array with ids for which i need to add new property with
value null. Db looks like this

```json
"Users" : {
    "Options" : {
    "Filters" : [ 
    UUID("c61a0cd6-1980-4c35-96cd-acf31a7a67fa"), 
    UUID("1c659dda-980e-4efe-b7ac-2d82ed643348")
            ]
        }
    }
```

What i need is to have Filters as an object:

```
"Filters" : [ 
_id: UUID("c61a0cd6-1980-4c35-96cd-acf31a7a67fa"), NewProperty: null },
_id: UUID("1c659dda-980e-4efe-b7ac-2d82ed643348"), NewProperty: null }
]
```

I've tried to work with `updateMany`, `$addFields` and `$addToSet` but with i've got no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { "Users.Filters": { $map: { 
     input: "$Users.Filters", 
     in: { _id: "$$this", NewProperty: null }
  } } } }
])
```

In order to update existing documents, use

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{ 'Users.Filter.Options': {$ne:null, $gt:[]} },
[
  { $set: { "Users.Filters": { $map: { 
     input: "$Users.Filters", 
     in: { _id: "$$this", NewProperty: null }
  } } } }
])
```

Comment: I wanted to filter out first collection with `$match 'Users.Filter.Options': {$ne:null, $gt:[]}` . And the output for aggregation looks ok, but it doesn;t save the new updated objects. I've tried to run the `updateMany` with that filter and your `$set...`  code but i've got in `can't convert undefined to object`